# Merging vectors very fast

Tags: c

I want to merge numeric vectors very fast. I found in a book that merging two vectors of size n1 and n2, takes proportional time with n1+n2. So merging three vectors of sizes n1,n2,n3, does order matters? And if it does, why?

EDIT:
Yes the vectors are ordered and the result has to by ordered.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you clarify?

Comment: You never mentioned whether the original vectors, nor the resulting merge, were *ordered*, and whether that ordering (whatever it may be) is to be maintained.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry I added the information

Comment: Why is that question tagged `C`? It is actually a general computer science question (complexitiy - big O).

Comment: well, "complexity" starts with a C...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging two sorted arrays in the generic case takes between the smaller of `n1` and `n2` and the sum `n1+n2-1` comparisons and `n1+n2` moves.

You can optimize special cases at very little cost, such as the cases where all values in one array are below all values in the other.  Doing this significantly improves the performance of `mergesort` on sorted and reverse sorted arrays.

If one of the arrays is significantly smaller than the other, binary searching elements of the smaller array in the larger array will significantly lower the number of comparison and allow for block moving elements from the larger array to the destination.

Careful implementation of the merging code will avoid testing array boundaries unnecessarily.

Here is some code:

```
static void merge(int *dest, const int *a1, size_t n1, const int *a2, size_t n2) {
    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0 || a1[n1 - 1] <= a2[0]) {
        /* trivial cases and arrays in order */
        memcpy(dest, a1, n1 * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(dest + n1, a2, n2 * sizeof(int));
        return;
    }
    if (a2[n2 - 1] < a1[0]) {
        /* arrays should be swapped */
        memcpy(dest, a2, n2 * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(dest + n2, a1, n1 * sizeof(int));
        return;
    }
    /* general case */
    for (const int *e1 = a1 + n1, *e2 = a2 + n2;;) {
        if (*a1 <= *a2) {
            *dest++ = *a1++;
            if (a1 >= e1) {
                memcpy(dest, a2, (e2 - a2) * sizeof(int));
                break;
            }
        } else {
            *dest++ = *a2++;
            if (a2 >= e2) {
                memcpy(dest, a1, (e1 - a1) * sizeof(int));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```